# Django in Google Cloud Run cant find /cloudsql socket

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a dockerized django application which I've built, uploaded to GCR and then deployed as a google cloud run service. However, when starting up I get the following error (from the cloud run logs):

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running locally and accepting 
connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/kingdoms-289503:us-west1:kingdomsdb/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My database settings for django look something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': "/cloudsql/kingdoms-289503:us-west1:kingdomsdb",
        'USER': "postgres",
        'PASSWORD': "password",
        'NAME': "postgres",
    }
}
```

And I've made sure to create the connection to the database

[image: cloudsql connection]

From what I understand, cloud run is supposed to magically mount a at /cloudsql that django can use to connect to postgres, but the error implies that it's not being mounted.

Is there an extra piece of configuration I would need to check to make sure that socket is there? Are there alternatives to connecting to cloudsql that don't involve this socket?

Comment: can you post your code on how you are connecting to the database? are you following this documentation https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#public-ip-default_1

cloud run won't create the /cloudsql directory for you. you must create it

Comment: Does your database have a public IP or did you removed it?

Comment: Did you redeploy after adding the Cloud SQL connection?

Comment: Does the `/cloudsql/` directory exist in your container? If this directory does not already exist, you must create it.

Comment: Check your IAM settings. The service account for your Cloud Run service needs to have permissions to access Cloud SQL. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi Creating the /cloudsql directory was the answer! Can you make your reply an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Hi @ForrestKeppler , I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Run won't create the /cloudsql directory for you. you must create it.

also, for further instructions on how to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run, you can consult this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#public-ip-default_1)

Comment: Cloud Run does create the /cloudsql directory automatically. I have tested it with shellinabox docker image. The folder is there but empty. I have the same project settings as @Forrest Keppler

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above by @glasnt, it could also be an ACL issue. The service account needs the `Cloud SQL Client` role. In the default case, `Default compute service account` is the principal ending in  `compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

My issue was that I wasn't given the option to add the role from where my newbie intuition led me, the Cloud Run service resource. Instead, go to the main IAM settings, IAM tab, and manually add the permission to the service account. If you don't see the service account in the list and thus can't edit it's roles, you can go to `Add +` (top toolbar) and manually enter the email address.

Comment: this worked for me if you want to add this role via glcoud command line `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_SLUG} --member=serviceAccount:${CLOUD_RUN_RUNNER_PRINCIPAL} --role=roles/cloudsql.client`